# Localizing JavaAnpr for local license plates

Tags: java, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am working with [JavaAnpr](http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/) to automatically recognize license plates. While it works well with European license plates, it doesn't with my country.  For example;

[image: License plate from my country]

How could I edit the recourse files and syntax XML to support other countries?

Comment: did you try other libraries as well?

Comment: Can you provide another sample image? I'm trying to figure it out. It's working fine with some kind of plates here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@michel_layyous - Here's the documentation by the author.  Read Page 57:
http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/anpr.pdf

syntax.xml is essentially a regex file.

Using this page as an example:
https://code.google.com/p/android-anpr/source/browse/trunk/res/raw/syntax.xml?r=21

```
<type name="russia">
   <char content="abcehkmoptxy"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcehkmoptxy"/>  
   <char content="abcehkmoptxy"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
</type>
```

This Russian license plate pattern is 8 characters.  The first character can be any of those letters.  The next 3 characters can be any number from their respective set.  The next 2 characters can be any of those letters from their respective set, and the last 2 characters can be any of those letters from their respective set.

The next Russian license plate is just like the first Russian license plate, except one key difference:

```
<type name="russia2">
   <char content="abcehkmoptxy"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcehkmoptxy"/>  
   <char content="abcehkmoptxy"/>
   <char content="012"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
</type>
```

The 6th character can only be a 0, 1, or 2.

I also found a relevant blurb on this page:
http://www.mp3car.com/software-and-software-development/124529-automatic-number-plate-recognition-anpr-3.html

I found a very similar license plate for your country, however it consists of two rows.  The first two numbers are on the top row, and there are 5 numbers on the bottom row.  It looks like your country has 7 digits for your particular style of plate.  I don't how the dot factors into the recognition of your plate, however, Page 58 of the author's documentation states:

> The correction of a plate means the replacement of
>   each invalid character by another one. If the
>   character
>   ( )
>   i
>   p
>   at the i
>   th
>   position of the plate
>   P
>   does not match the selected pattern
>   ( )
>   `
>   sel
>   P
>   , it will
>   be replaced by the first valid one from
>   ( )
>   s
>   y
>   .
>   ( )
>   s
>   y
>   is a sorted vector of output activities denoting
>   how much the recognized character is similar to an
>   individual character from the alphabet.
>   Heuristic analysis of a segmented plate can sometim
>   es incorrectly evaluate non-character
>   elements as characters. Acceptance of the non-chara
>   cter elements causes that the recognized
>   plate will contain redundant characters. Redundant
>   characters occur usually on sides of the
>   plate, but rarely in the middle.
>   If the recognized plate number is longer than the l
>   ongest syntax pattern, we can select the
>   nearest pattern, and drop the redundant characters
>   according to it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  It has better support across various countries.    The library is written in C++ (as opposed to Java) but that should be easy to hook up using JNI.

Comment: As i know it is not free yes?