# JavaAnpr for local plate recognition

Tags: java, ocr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am using JavaAnpr to recognize for my country(Kazakhstan) number plates. It doesn't recognize correctly. I looked these links: [JavaANPR local plate recegtion (Localizing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113523/javaanpr-local-plate-recegtion-localizing),

[Localizing JavaAnpr for local license plates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596684/localizing-javaanpr-for-local-license-plates)
and I modified syntax.xml and size of image, but still getting an error.

This is my syntax.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<structure>
    <type name="kazakhstan">
        <char content="k"/>
        <char content="z"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
        <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
        <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
    </type>
    <type name="kazakhstan2">
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
        <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
        <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
        <char content="0123456789"/>
    </type>
</structure>
```

I have 2 issue

1. By [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko0qY.png) I get wrong result
2. By [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksyFl.png) get nothing(null)

This is very **important** for me. I wait impatiently answer. Thank you for help!

Comment: For debugging using the report generator, take a look at https://github.com/oskopek/javaanpr/blob/master/docs/howto-use-reports.adoc